# Como atualizar dicionários e criar um novo caso haja repetição de chave?

Tags: python, string, dicionário

A intenção é que ele leia qualquer valor de entrada e crie variáveis para cada índice da string. Como não consegui, fiz essa gambiara, gerando duas listas e um dicionário que atualiza em um dicionário fixo, o problema é que em nomes que letras repetem ele soma os valores na mesma chave.
Fiz dessa forma pq preciso acessar cada um dos valores separadamente em diferentes variáveis no resto do programa

Exemplo:

CARLOS - {'C': 3, 'A': 1, 'R': 18, 'L': 12, 'O': 15, 'S': 19}

ANA -    {'A': 1, 'N': 14}

Alguma ideia de como posso solucionar ou tenho que refazer pra conseguir acessar cada um dos valores de acordo com a entrada?

```
def Convert(string):
    list1=[]
    list1[:0]=string
    return list1

nome= input ("digite nome: ")

dic = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4, "E": 5, 'F': 6, 'G': 7, 'H': 8, 'I': 9,
       'J': 10, 'K': 11, 'L': 12, 'M': 13, 'N': 14, 'O': 15, 'P': 16, 'Q': 17,
       'R': 18, 'S': 19, 'T': 20, 'U': 21, 'V': 22, 'W': 23, 'X': 24, 'Y': 25, 'Z': 26}

tam = (len(nome))
letra = []

letra = list(range(0, tam))

novodic = {}
for i in range(len(Convert(nome))):
  novodic[Convert(nome)[i]] = letra[i]

for k_d1 in novodic:
    if k_d1 in dic:
        novodic[k_d1] = dic[k_d1]

print (nome)
print(Convert(nome))
print (type(Convert(nome)))
print(letra)
print(type(letra))
print(novodic)
print(type(novodic))
```

Comment: E qual deveria ser o resultado para a string "ANA"? Não ficou muito claro o que vc quer fazer...

Comment: O que quero é que indiferente da quantidade de caracteres de entrada, o sistema pegue ele e correlacione com um valor pré-determinado. O fato de eu ter criado as bibliotecas foi por ter sido a única forma de conseguir. Comecei a estudar dev tem pouco mais de um mês, então acredito que haja outras formas, mas até agora não consegui. Esse já é o terceiro post que faço, os outros dois foram fechados pq diziam já haver uma resposta.

Comment: Falaram para usar loop, for ou while. Pelo pouco que entendo, tentei, mas o sistema não a aceito criar variáveis dentro de laços e exportar elas para uso caso necessário. Cheguei a criar de outra forma, estipulando 7 variáveis (para uma alavra com 7 caracteres), mas quando entro com uma palavra menor ele falha.

Comment: Mas qual deve ser o resultado? Se a string for "ANA", como deve ser o dicionário resultante?

Comment: Sim, ele deveria retornar o ANA. Na verdade quero apenas que ele guarde os valores. A biblioteca fixa terá todos os outros caracteres do teclado. podia usar o ord(cha), e os valores ASCII, mas quero estipular os valores. No final preciso de 5 variáveis. Ou seja, se a entrada for ANA, usa essas três e cria outras duas, se for PEDRO, o sistema usa os valores correspondentes, mas se for GUILHERME, cria outras operações para retornar apenas cinco variáveis (concatena, soma, multiplica, entra em uma equação, etc).

Comment: @hkotsubo, ele não vai dizer abertamente, vai evitar máximo dizer que quer obter isso `{'A': 1, 'N': 14, 'A': 1}` pois sabe que não é possível mas acredita que poderá surgir alguém com uma gambiarra "mágica".  
Vitor Guarise, seja direto com o hkotsubo ele é especialista em estrutura de dados e poderá sugerir alternativas viáveis e performáticas que resolvam o seu problema.

Comment: O resultado deveria ser ANA apenas pq preciso das variáveis. ANNA!=ANA!=VIC. Quero ter bem estipulado os valore pq nomes diferentes podem até possuir valore finais de soma ou multiplicação, mas não deixam de ser diferentes.

Comment: Continuo sem entender. Acho mais fácil se vc [edit] a pergunta e colocar alguns exemplos, porque eu não consegui entender o que são essas variáveis, pra que elas servem, o que elas tem a ver com soma e multiplicação, etc.

Comment: Indiferente dos caracteres, eles deverão retornar no máximo 5 variáveis. O nome ANA - retorna 3, as outras duas eu crio. o Nome Vítor cria 5, então o sistema não vai precisar criar mais variáveis, o nome hkotsubo, tem uma entrada com 7 valores, elas entrarão em outras fórmulas que resultarão em 5 variáveis.

Comment: Entrada - STRING - Saida - VALORES FLOAT relacionados a valores pré-existentes (biblioteca ou qualquer outra coisa)

Comment: Vitor, por favor clique em [edit] e coloque essas regras na própria pergunta. É melhor assim porque lá tem mais espaço para vc elaborar com detalhes, colocar vários exemplos, etc.

Comment: ENTRADA ANA- SAIDA ( 1, 14, 1), v1=1, v2=14, v3=1

Comment: Se só quer os valores, por que não cria uma lista (por exemplo, uma lista contendo os números 1, 14 e 1), e limita o tamanho dela a 5? Aí nem precisa de dicionário

Comment: Veja se o ajuda: https://ideone.com/x7sRnU

Comment: @AugustoVasques Ele disse que tem que ser no máximo 5 valores, então poderia usar `entrada[:5].upper()` (se entendi direito)

Answer (score -2):

Pelo que eu entendi voce queria converter o nome numa sequencia de números do seu dicionário, Bom consegui fazer para voce se for isso.

```
def Convert(string):
    conversion = []
    string = string.upper()
    dic = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4, "E": 5, 'F': 6, 'G': 7, 'H': 8, 'I': 9,
       'J': 10, 'K': 11, 'L': 12, 'M': 13, 'N': 14, 'O': 15, 'P': 16, 'Q': 17,
       'R': 18, 'S': 19, 'T': 20, 'U': 21, 'V': 22, 'W': 23, 'X': 24, 'Y': 25, 'Z': 26}
    for i in range(len(string)):
        conversion.append(dic.get(string[i]))
    return conversion
    
nome = input("Digite seu nome: ")
print(Convert(nome))
```

Comment: Em python isso se faz com uma linha `print(list(map(lambda c:ord(c)-ord('@'), input("Digite seu nome: ").upper())))`

Comment: Funcionou muito bem, Metronomy31, muito obrigado mesmo. Agora vou estudar o que vc fez pra entender.

Comment: Usando a linha indica, o map e o lambda funciona até uma parte. Ao inserir novos valores no dicionário, ele carrega outro valor. No caso inseri letras com acentos. Mas igual obrigado pela dica, vou olhar com mais calma pra entender melhor o map e o lambda

Comment: de boa, só de ter ajudado, já fico feliz, pra entender o codigo é so lembrar que a string no python tb possui indices como uma lista e um tuple por exemplo.

Comment: @VitorGuarise e Metronomy31, não precisa desse `range`, strings são iteráveis e dá pra percorrê-la diretamente: https://ideone.com/Rlike2 - Não ficou claro o que fazer se a string tiver um caractere que não existe no dicionário (esse código que eu fiz não valida isso). E claro que tem várias melhorias possíveis (como por exemplo passar o dicionário como parâmetro da função, etc)

Comment: verdade, acho que passar o dicionário como argumento seria interessante tb